# Gridview Error on editing with dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have grid view with folowing complete code With Msaccess DB.I have used the decode function in sql query.When i press the edit button on grid view it shows folowing error

"DropDownList2' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value"
My SQL Data source code is below

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString2 %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [EMAILS] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [EMAILS] ([Email], [FULLNAME],[FLAG]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Email, FULLNAME, switch(FLAG = 1, 'Allowed', Flag = 0, 'Not Allowed') AS FLAG FROM EMAILS"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [EMAILS] SET [Email] = ?, [FULLNAME] = ?,[FLAG] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FULLNAME" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FLAG" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>

                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FULLNAME" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FLAG" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And Grid View Code is bellow

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None"
            BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="821px" EmptyDataText="No Emails Found">
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                    SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FULLNAME" HeaderText="Full Name" SortExpression="FULLNAME" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flag" SortExpression="FLAG">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" SelectedValue="<%# Bind('FLAG') %>" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Allowed</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Not Allowed</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FLAG") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small"
                ForeColor="#FFFFCC" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#804000" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Please tell me what possible error is here

Comment: Please anyone answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check weather the value in Field `flag` of the row you are trying to edit, is available in the DropDownList in EditItemTemplate

And try removing `AppendDataBoundItems="True"` in DropDownList in EditItemTemplate

Comment: Sir I add the actual value of Db In Dropdwon now it works Fine On IIS but when i upload it on ftp server then it Generat this error when i update the grid "Operation must use an updateable query." what can i do for this ?

Comment: @user1099825 Try this http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/fix-operation-must-use-updateable-query-error-5635/

Comment: From above site: To fix this problem, right click on the folder which holds the Microsoft Access database & choose properties. Use the Security tab in Explorer to adjust the properties for this folder so that the Internet Guest account has the correct writable permissions.

Comment: Sir I have set the Permissions of Guest Accout on folder and then replace the folder on ftp but still error is same

Comment: @user1099825 'Guest' or 'Internet Guest' Account??? its  IUSR_<computername>. (or keep only 'everyone' in user list and give it full permission & try...